# php or JavaScript check if a user has visited google

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, caching, browser-history

I have jquery minified and I am using it in  my site but my site mayn't be visited that much as google and google is hosting a jquery from **cloud**. and so I wanna check if a user has visited google. If he has, then include that script google has included else show my site's script. I want to do this because most people use google and by visiting it, the jquery script is cached in user's device hence, resulting in faster loading. So I want to check if a user has visited google or not. If s/he has, then include that script as

```
<script src="// SCRIPT name"></src>
```

So all I want is the code but I don't know how to do that. Please help

Comment: Even if the user had been on Google (by which I take to mean that their browser has seen and downloaded the jquery lib) you'd still need to include it in your markup to be used. So just always include one or the other.

Comment: @Jon Stirling but I want to be very careful as if he hasn't, then it would too much time fetching the cloud script and i don't want that to happen

Comment: I can almost guarantee that getting the lib from google will be faster than getting it from your own servers. It's for the browser to decide if it uses what's in its cache, not for a websites. Use the cloud one, the browser will use cached version if it can, otherwise will download, let it do its job.

Comment: @Jon Stirling still I want the script. If you can gimme such script then do please

Comment: 'fraid I don't know of such a script. Not convinced it's actually even possible to check.

Comment: Deleted. Jon, don't mind

Comment: Still there might be a way to check. And yes that cache question is like that